# Using a button click to modify an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious if there is a way to use something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
    $().addremove();
```

to toggle a modification to an html element, like, say adding and removing a class to the closest `<li>` via the button click.

like changing `<li>example</li>` to `<li class="abc">example<li>` and if there is a way, could someone please let me know how far off I am?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and have you tried it? It's probably quicker to try it yourself and then come back if you have specific code that you are having issues with. Check the jquery docs for the specific functionality you are looking for (in this case probably `addClass` or `removeClass`)

Comment: Is it ANY `li`? What is the relationship?

Comment: the nearest li to the button

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzztkzak/) Ok, this is what I am working on, and it seems to work for the most part. Clicking on the star icon toggles the .fav class on the `<li>` then clicking the button with id="fav" toggles the view of only yellow star. But if I scroll down further on the list, clicking on the star sends me back to the top of the list. Is that from changing the DOM structure? Is there another way to accomplish this "favorites" view?

Answer (score 1):

i have done a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9z57wyd/)

i have used `toggleClass` to add/remove class.

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
  $('li').toggleClass('abc');
});
```

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what i was trying to do!

Comment: you are welcome mate

Comment: so this works well, but can it be done with the closest li only?

Comment: yes it can be, but hey if your DOM structure changes it breaks things, lets not try to make "DOM dependent" code and rather write independent code.

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzztkzak/) Ok, this is what I am working on, and it seems to work for the most part. Clicking on the star icon toggles the .fav class on the `<li>` then clicking the button with id="fav" toggles the view of only yellow star. But if I scroll down further on the list, clicking on the star sends me back to the top of the list. Is that from changing the DOM structure? Is there another way to accomplish this "favorites" view?

Comment: yes, you can use `javascript:void(0)` in `href` attribute to prevent this behavior. like i did in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynqagk4L/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('abc');
});
```

I think this is basically what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no toggleId() kind of thing.
However, I have two methods to do it.

**Method 1:**

```
$('button').click(function(){
 if($('your-div').attr('id')=='theID'){
   $('your-div').attr('id', '');
 }
 else{
  $('your-div').attr('id', 'theID');
 }
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
$('your-div').attr('id', ($('your-div').attr('id') === 'theID' ? '' : 'theID'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose HTML:

```
<div id="button"> button
</div>
<li>example</li>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
  // use next() to get & change li's class
  $(this).next().attr('class','abc');
  // or use selector directly to target element and modify its class
  $('some_selector').attr('class','abc');
});
```

For nearby element, check jQuery API [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) or [sliblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Besides, the [selectors part of jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addClass() and removeClass() method of jQuery to achieve that. You may also use toggleClass() to switch a class on and off for an element.

Please check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samratdebroy/kx4z6fzd/3/).

I am selecting the particular `<li>` and removing the assigned class and adding the new one as demonstrated below:

```
    $("#change").on('click', function(event) {
        $($("li")[0]).removeClass('bright').addClass('sober');
        $($("li")[1]).removeClass('sober').addClass('pale');
        $($("li")[2]).removeClass('pale').addClass('bright');
    });
```

Thanks.